# print only method signatures in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java class with too many methods (problematic design, I know) and in order to have a clear view and separate its responsibilities into smaller classes,

I want to print all the method signatures from this class.

How can I do that on intellij (currently intellij 12.1.7)?

Added:

I ended up using windows command prompt's equivalent to grep, as @beerbajay suggested.

`findstr /C:private /C:public /C:protected /C:internal fileName.java`

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [structure view](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-with-structure-views.html)...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I want something much simpler. I want to print a hard copy of the signatures, not inside Java.
@beerbajay do you know how to hardcopy print a structure view? (didn't find in the documentation..)

NiravPrajapati reflection will work, but will be an overhead for my one time print :)

Comment: Take a screenshot? grep for public/private/protected?

Comment: I ended up using windows' equivalent to grep:
findstr /C:private /C:public /C:protected /C:internal fileName.java

@beerbajay I would vote your answer even more if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the strcuture view. Or simply rely on intellitext.

Or create a uml diagram (usign built in intellij tool), and print that off.

or even better refactor, so you don;t need to do this.